# Use XSL to parse XML "color" attribute to fill a table cell

Tags: html, xslt

I'm learning XML and I'm running into the following problem: I have an attribute in my XML file which can have a color as content (e.g. `<color>red</color>`), but I don't know how to use it.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
    <car year="2002" manufacturer="Jet" model="Sardine Can 1.6L">
        <meter>95664</meter>
        <color>silver</color>
        <price>099900</price>
        <dealersecurity buyback="no"/>
    </car>
    <car year="2004" manufacturer="Jet" model="Sardine Can 2.0">
        <meter>81283</meter>
        <color>red</color>
        <price>129900</price>
        <dealersecurity buyback="no"/>
    </car>
    <car year="2007" manufacturer="Jet" model="Sardine Can 2.0">
        <meter>49741</meter>
        <color>black</color>
        <price>169999</price>
        <dealersecurity buyback="yes"/>
    </car>
</cars>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/cars">
    <html>
      <head><title>Second Hand Sardine Cans</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/></head>
      <body>
      <h1>Second Hand Sardine Cans</h1>
      <table border="1"><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th>KMs</th><th>Color</th><th>Price</th><th>Warranty</th><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cars/car">
  <tr><xsl:for-each select="cars/car"/>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@manufacturer" /></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@model" /></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@year" /></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="meter" /></td>
        <xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="meter"/>

  <xsl:template match="color">
  <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="price">
  <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I have until now:
[image: Result until now]

But instead of it saying "Red" or "Black", I want that cell to fill with that exact color.

Thanks!

Edit: I fixed it with the help of Dimitre's answer. I added `<td bgcolor="{color}"><xsl:value-of select="color" /></td>` below `<td><xsl:value-of select="meter" /></td>`

Comment: Just a side remark about terminology: `<color>red</color>` is not an attribute, as you call it, it's an *element*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just change in your transformation**:

```
   <tr>
```

**to**:

```
   <tr bgcolor="{color}">
```

**Or, if you really want to have just one cell with that color, use in the template that matches `color`**:

```
   <td bgcolor="{.}">
```

Comment: That works partially, as in that it colors the complete rows and not only the cell that contains the name for the color. See http://i46.tinypic.com/20segt3.png
Edit: In other words: I want to hit that specific <td>, but adding bgcolor="{color}" doesn't color the <td>.
Edit 2: Fixed, will accept your answer and specify it in my question.

Comment: @Rvervuurt, I didn't really think that you wanted to have a special cell for the color. If so, use: `<td bgcolor="{../color}">Whatever text needed here</td>`. Please, see the updated answer.